# iOS pushNotification Remove from notification center Just after it's arrived

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I test push notification on development APNS server.

Notification is Remove from notification center Just after it's arrived.

is there issues related Device. or coding from server side which sends push notification from APNS to the device ?

**Testing Device Details** - 
`Iphone 5C`
`iOS 10.3.3`

[Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hCqwc9tc1kTGN1RWVsRFlFejg/view) For View Video

Thank you !!

Comment: Show your code for notification receipt handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because of your device date is greater from today's date. Please make sure that your device date is not greater or it should not be different from the current date.

Comment: Thank you..!! very deep observation @sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove notification from center.

1. User manually taps/click on notification or deletes notification.
2. Programatically set application badge count to zero.

In your case if your are not manually taking an action on notification in center then there may be following reason:

For iOS 10 onwards, following function/method (belongs to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate) handles receipt of notification. You may have set application badge count to 0 (zero) in this function.

```
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // check here for application badge count setup
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to achieve, rather that it's their current situation and would like a fix.

Comment: You may right.. lets confirm with OP.. but he/she is not replying since an half hour

Comment: @Krunal Thank you for explaining. it's just date problem. The date was set 2018 year in the device.